# use regex to detect if a string contains two newlines

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text in a html page which is generated from a mysql query and it includes newlines. Im able to show the newlines in the HTML by using the `<pre>` tag. This enables the text to show each paragraph without need to use `<p>` tags.

Now I would like to programmatically (using javascript) emphasise the first paragraph by placing an outline around it. In order to to so I would need to place the first paragraph in a `<div>`.

I can obtain the string of the text by

```
var preElement = document.querySelector("pre");
var text = preElement.innerHTML;
```

How can I use regex to detect the first paragraph where there are two newlines so that I can place it inside `<div>` elements?

Comment: Can you give some sample about `two newlines` ?

Comment: Why are you so adverse to using a `<p>`?

Comment: @zer00ne - as mentioned the text is coming straight out of a mysql query. the mysql record retains the paragraphs so im able to reproduce the paragraphs by using the pre tag

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input PRE's innerHTML? Is that pure string or it has HTML markup in it?

Comment: @thang - on BBedit the newline symbol looks like a dash with a vertical line going down from the right hand side

Comment: What means `inside <div> elements` (plural)? Can you provide the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure (since missing in the question) what the input and desired output are, but

use `.replace()` with the following regex, that captures the matching group and inserts it into a DIV:

```js
const elPre = document.querySelector("pre");
elPre.innerHTML = elPre.textContent.replace(/^([^\n\n]+)/, "<div>$1</div>");
```

```css
pre div { background: gold; padding: 1rem; }
```

```html
<pre id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit ullam vitae, quisquam molestias.

Fugit eaque officiis aspernatur voluptatum, rem quod minus temporibus
inventore obcaecati repellat nostrum tenetur blanditiis veniam.</pre>
```

Alternatively, here's an example using split and join

```js
const elPre = document.querySelector("pre");

const [title, ...rest] = elPre.textContent.split("\n");
elPre.innerHTML = `<div>${title}</div>${rest.join("\n")}`;
```

```css
pre div { background: gold; padding: 1rem; }
```

```html
<pre id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit ullam vitae, quisquam molestias.

Fugit eaque officiis aspernatur voluptatum, rem quod minus temporibus
inventore obcaecati repellat nostrum tenetur blanditiis veniam.</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this - you can simply replace the newlines with your closing `</div>` tag.  That said, I think this is a pretty weird approach to page layout and I doubt it's really what you should be doing.

```js
var preElement = document.querySelector("pre");
var html = '<div>' + preElement.innerHTML.replace("\n\n", "</div>");
preElement.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<pre>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis

iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
</pre>
```